# Natural isomorphism between tensor product and exterior product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I am requesting help with the following problem.

Below all rings are commutative with unit, and for a ring $R$, we define an $R$-algebra to be a ring $R'$ with ring homomorphism $f: R \to R'$. This induces a $R$-module structure on $R'$ by defining scalar multiplication as $ab := f(a)b$.

Let $R$ be ring, $A$ an $R$-module, and $S$ a $R$-algebra. For every positive integer $k$ construct an isomorphism $(\bigwedge^{k} A) \otimes_{R} S = \bigwedge^{k} (A \otimes_{R} S)$.

I know that I should use the universal properties of the tensor and exterior products. But I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The notation below will look as though I'm working with left modules instead of right, but in fact, in working in the commutative ring case, every left module $M$ can be rendered as a right module by the definition $mr = rm$, and in fact in this way all (left) modules can be rendered as bimodules.

The following is a somewhat "high-level" categorical explanation.

---

To prove this, it suffices to observe that the functor

$$S \otimes_R -: R\textbf{-Mod} \to S\textbf{-Mod}$$
preserves colimits and is a symmetric monoidal functor. The latter means that the canonical map

$$(S \otimes_R M) \otimes_S (S \otimes_R N) \to S \otimes_R (M \otimes_R N)$$
defined by the assignment
$$(s \otimes m) \otimes (t \otimes n) \mapsto st \otimes (m \otimes n)$$
is an isomorphism that is suitably compatible with the associativity and symmetry isomorphisms pertaining to the tensor products $\otimes_R$ and $\otimes_S$ (see the nLab, starting [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+functor) and following links as needed). The inverse is defined by $s \otimes (m \otimes n) \mapsto (s \otimes m) \otimes (1_S \otimes n)$, where $1_S$ denotes the multiplicative identity of $S$.
It is well-known that $S \otimes_R -$ preserves colimits, because it is left adjoint (see the discussion [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extension+of+scalars#general_abstract)) to the functor

$$S\textbf{-Mod} \to R\textbf{-Mod}$$
which takes an $S$-module $A$ to the $R$-module with scalar multiplication given by the definition $r \cdot a = f(r)a$, where $f: R \to S$ is the given ring homomorphism that gives $S$ its $R$-algebra structure.

The reason this suffices is that the exterior power $\Lambda^k M$ is expressed directly in terms of colimits and tensor products with their symmetric monoidal structure. Consider for example how $\Lambda^k$ is constructed in $R\textbf{-Mod}$: it is a coequalizer of two maps

$$\bigoplus_{\sigma \in S_k} M^{\otimes_R k} \rightrightarrows M^{\otimes_R k}$$
where the first map, evaluated at the summand indexed by a group element $\sigma$, is the map $M^{\otimes_R k} \to M^{\otimes_R k}$ obtained by permuting tensor factors according to the permutation $\sigma$, and the second map evaluated at the same summand is multiplication by $\mathrm{sign}(\sigma)$.

Comment: Nice solution; I will be able to appreciate it once I learn category theory

Comment: I wasn't sure how much you knew, but since the instruction was to prove it by exploiting universal properties, which is part of category theory, I took my chances. Feel free to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: Oh, I meant the universal property that says "every multilinear map from the tensor product factors through the tensor map" and "every alternating map from the exterior product factors through exterior map"

Comment: Sure, and this is what I was getting at at the end. But some time later today, I'll bring out this point more explicitly.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm looking forward to it!